# stocked in ubuntu grub rescue

Tags: grub

I have followed lots of suggestions but got stocked and nothing works...
on Hd I have windows7 and ubuntu  that I don't care about, nor of all the others partitions except one with saved documents, I am happy to wipe the lot but it seams impossible to get any further..if I go into the BIOS and leave just the CD-rom as bootable it tells me that there isn't an operating system,dead end, if I add the HD then I get the Grub rescue and can't boot from the cd???
this is as far as I got[image] 
HELP...

this are my bios settings( the machine was built in 2006):
[image]

I have ubuntu 9.1 and an older version on separate disks
I have a windows 7 disk 
I also have a linux kali 2.0 ( this is the one I wanted to install)
I first cleared a partition to create space, and this is where it went wrong...
on the system there is windows on one partition, the others were: system reserved, ubuntu old, ubuntu 9.1, swap resered, data storage...
apart for the data partition I don't care to loose the rest....
the strange thing is that I can't boot from a CD

Comment: (Posted on behalf of mkdrive2)

 I have the following questions: 

1. Can you boot with the sequence 
`<pre>set root='(hd0,6)' 
chainloader /EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi 
boot</pre>` 

2. What is on your bootable CD? 

3. Are you booting in EFI mode? (Check in BIOS options) 

4. If yes, could you try legacy booting mode and/or disable secure boot? 

5. What exactly do you want to do? (Fresh install of Windows/Linux?)

6. After changing BIOS settings, try booting from the CD, not hard disk.

NOTE: please update information in the question, not in comments.

Comment: boot >> boot priority ordre >> make sur that first one is  IDE cd and N°2 is HDD Next step > advanced > Intel Robson = Disabled

Answer (score 0):

You can try one from the 2 solutions ( N°2 is the best) :

1) From an Ubuntu live-session (boot your computer on a Ubuntu live-CD or live-USB then choose "Try Ubuntu")

- connect to the Internet
- open a new Terminal, then type the following commands (press Enter after each line):

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair

  sudo apt-get update

  sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
  ```

Launch Boot-Repair from the dash

Then click the "Recommended repair" button. When repair is finished Reboot

2) From grub rescue:

type the following commands:

```
  ls (hd0,6)/
  set root=(hd0,6)
  set prefix=(hd0,6)/boot/grub
  insmod normal
  normal
```

Generally:

if you get error try with the others partitions

The right partition ( after runing `ls (hdX)/` ) will have an output like `Filesystem is ext2`

Comment: Hi No one is not possible as it doesn't let me boot from a CD, if I tell the Bos to ignore the HD, I get the message that no operating system is installed??

Comment: number two, the only partition that gives me a lost = found is (hd0,6) the others don't give me anything

Comment: number two, the only partition that gives me a lost + found is (hd0,6) the others don't give me anything, when I do the sequence with (hd0,6) after insmod normal I get file not found...the others unknown filesystem after the ls(hdx,y)/....

Comment: try this command " insmod.old '' or " insmod linux''

Comment: thaks.. insmod.old gets me one step further but when I type normal gives me unknown comand...if I do insmod linux gives me error: the symbol 'grub_puts_' not found

Comment: tried again and insmod.old actually gives me unknown command

Comment: try : linux /boot/vmlinuz root=/dev/sd6 ro     then : initrd /boot/initrd   and
 finally : boot

Comment: tried..unknown command '/linux/boot/vmlinuz'